# Connect to a server with TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there any way to connect to a server with t-sql?

I want to assign a shortcut to it

I already tried ':Connect -serverName ...'

Thanks for your time

Edit: I just want to do what "connect to database engine" does with SQL commands

Comment: You'll have to be clearer about what you want. Your question is a bit vague at the moment.

Comment: e.g. Are you trying to create a shortcut for windows, so you can just double click that and it connects to the relevant server in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: No I have about 10 servers and I want to connect 1.1.1.1for example with it's username and password I don't want to open the connect window then select server and the connect I want to assign a shortcut i.e. ctrl+0 to connect directly to a server

Comment: Have you seen Server Groups? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-management-studio/create-or-edit-a-server-group-sql-server-management-studio

Comment: @milney thanks for your time this is good but I want to assign shortcuts to do that if possible

Answer (score 1):

You can set up linked servers like this:

```
 EXEC sp_addlinkedServer N'remoteSqlServer\Instance', N'SQL Server'
 EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'remoteSqlServer\Instance', @useself = 'FALSE', 
                           @rmtuser = N'user', @rmtpassword = N'password'
```

(replace the 'remoteSqlServer\instance' name with your actual server name and instance name, and 'user' with the user to log in with, and 'password' with that user's login password)

From then on, you can reference the server using the same dot notation that you use to reference different databases on the same server:

```
SELECT * FROM [server\instance].[database].[schema].[tableName]
```

You do not have to 'connect' to these other servers in SQL Server Management Studio... you can just be on one server, and reference all the others, and mix them into your queries as you need.